# How can i add a Sprite to a sprite group in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

this is my code.  I have tried everything I can think of to get It to work, but I cant figure it out.  I added the whole code, if you can find the error it would help tremoundously.

```
#Librarys/Modules and Stuffs
import pygame, sys
from gamebase import *
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


#Variables
MainSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


#Classes
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

player = Player()
MainSprites.add(player)
print(MainSprites)
#Functions


#Main
def Main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: did you try instantiating Player and adding it to MainSprites like - `MainSprites.add(<player instance>)` ?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create an instance of a sprite and add it to a declared spritegroup. So in your case it would look like this:

```
MainSprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


#Classes
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

player = Player()
MainSprites.add(player)
```

edit: corrected the class code. Replaced:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite()):
```

with:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
```

and that fixes your recursion problem.

Comment: I tried what you said, and even used your exact code but I keep getting an error. it says, Runtime Error: Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: There's nothing in this code that's recursive to cause that error. Somewhere in your code you probably have something calling itself over and over again accidentally. Post more of your code if you want me to take a look.

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the recursion problem

Comment: Glad it seems to have worked out. Mind accepting the answer if it helped you?